# Example of compactly supported, closed, smooth $2$-form in $\mathbb{R}^3$

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-forms

I want to find an example of compactly supported closed, smooth $2$-form in $\mathbb{R}^3$. I know that for a $2$-form $$w = a dx\wedge dy + b dx\wedge dz + c dy\wedge dz$$ and its exterior derivative is $$dw= (\frac{\partial a}{\partial z}-\frac{\partial b}{\partial y}+\frac{\partial c}{\partial x})dx\wedge dy\wedge dz$$ So I want to pick a compact supported, smooth function $\phi:\mathbb{R}^3 \to \mathbb{R}$ that is symmetric across $x,y,z$ and choose $\psi(x,y,z)=\phi(x,2y,z)$ such that $2\partial_x\psi= 2\partial_z\psi = \partial_y\psi$. Then choose $$w(p) = \psi(p) dx\wedge dy + \psi(p)  dx\wedge dz + \psi(p)  dy\wedge dz$$ and by equation above $dw = 0$ so $w$ is closed. I wonder if this is legitimate. The question is that the solution is not symmetric and there is $2y$ for seemingly no reason, so I think I probably did something wrong.

Comment: You'd better check the details carefully. What does symmetric mean and where are you evaluating partial derivatives? I would recommend working in spherical coordinates with a function of $\rho$ compactly supported in $(0,\infty)$. Then what?

Comment: So you mean use something like $\rho dr \wedge d\theta$ whose derivative is $d\rho \wedge dr \wedge d\theta$ which is naturally $0$ as $d\rho$ only involves $dr$ term?

Comment: I see so by working in spherical coordinates the set $\{v \in \mathbb{R}^3: r \in K\}$ is naturally compact for any compact $K$. So I just need to find any smooth compactly supported function $\phi$ in $\mathbb{R}$ and make the form just taking as $\phi(r)$ and constant with respect to other arguments

Comment: The zero $2$-form is of compact support.

Comment: @ArcticChar: Blah, blah, blah.